# Separating helper functions into a separate C++ header/source file

Tags: c++, oop, abstraction

So in my current project, I have main.cpp, fruit.h, and fruit.cpp.

In main.cpp, it current looks like this:

```
#include "fruit.h"
#include <Mouth.h>

int main() {
  Fruit orange;
  orange.wash(); //wash is a method of the Fruit class

  Mouth mouth = NULL; //Mouth is a library I am using
  if(mouth_init() != 0) {
    return 1;
  }

  mouth = create_new_mouth();

  if (mouth == NULL) {
    return 1;
  }

  mouth_eat(orange);

  clean_up_mouth();
  mouth = NULL;
}
```

Obviously this is an overly simplified example, as my actual library init and exit functions are more complex. But I was thinking of taking out the initialization and clean up code from main, and create helper functions. Now I could place these helper functions within main.cpp, but I was thinking of creating a new C++ file called mouth.cpp, and putting the functions in there. But since mouth.cpp won't have a class, and will just contain my helper functions, is this legal or even good practice to do? If it is allowed, should I create a mouth.h file containing the function declarations as well?

Comment: You can store the return value of `create_new_mouth()` and create a wapper for that, as for the other functions just making them helper functions would be a good approach ( perhaps making them static in the same wrapper class)

Comment: @JameyD can you please elaborate a bit more on what you mean by creating a wrapper for create_new_mouth()?

Answer (score 2):

Having only functions in header/cpp files is totally Ok for C++. But, IMO, it would be more elegant to use a simple class for library initialization and de-initialization.

```
struct MouthLibHolder
{
    MouthLibHolder(const MouthLibHolder&) = delete;
    MouthLibHolder& operator=(const MouthLibHolder&) = delete;

    MouthLibHolder() 
    { 
        if (!mouth_init())
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to init Mouth library");
    }
    ~MouthLibHolder()
    {
        clean_up_mouth();
    }
};
```

Then you may use this code in your main function like:

```
main() 
{
    try {
        MouthLibHolder mouthLib;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The holder might be implemented in separate h/cpp files.

Comment: Even better if you delete copy-constructor and assignment to respect rule of 3.

Answer (score 1):

Create both the .cpp and .h file and make sure to wrap everything in a `namespace`.
You may also consider defining a static class as helper which has these functions as methods

Answer (score 0):

> But since mouth.cpp won't have a class, and will just contain my helper functions, is this legal or even good practice to do?

You can put every function and/or global object into separate .cpp file. That still would be "legal" but most probably unpractical. Good practice is a matter of taste so it is subjective. You probably should put that functions to separate namespace or class or both, but even if you would not do that for small or medium project it could be perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is legal and good practice also. Write helper functions declarations in header file and their definitions in source file.